# Multiprocessing---Restarting Process Logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

In the multiprocessing a new process is started but is it like on every loop?
For example- I am doing an image processing on multiple pages(200 pages), so does a new process starts in each of those pages. Or if have 4 core processor, then in one loop eight processes of python would start and then in the next loop, the process would continue without restarting python? Or correct me if i have got my basics wrong.......

Comment: it depends on how you write your code. If you'll add it to the post, someone can assist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to carry out the same operation on multiple images, using a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` would take care of most of these details for you. You only have to write the function to process an image.

I would suggest using either the `concurrent.futures.as_completed()` method or the `Executor.map()` method.

If you want to process images by using the `subprocess` to call an external program, use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead. Below is an complete example that does just that to convert TIFF files to PDF.
You can find this script and several others like it in my [scripts repository](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/scripts).

(Note that the `ProcessPoolExecutor` can be used in the same way as the `ThreadPoolExecutor` since they both inherit from the `Executor` class.)

```
from functools import partial
import argparse
import concurrent.futures as cf
import logging
import os
import re
import subprocess as sp
import sys

__version__ = '1.4'


def main():
    """
    Entry point for tifftopdf.
    """
    args = setup()
    func = tiffconv
    if args.jpeg:
        logging.info('using JPEG compression.')
        func = partial(tiffconv, jpeg=True, quality=args.quality)
    with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as tp:
        for fn, rv in tp.map(func, args.files):
            if rv == 0:
                logging.info(f'finished "{fn}"')
            else:
                logging.error(f'conversion of {fn} failed, return code {rv}')


def setup():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    parser.add_argument(
        '--log',
        default='warning',
        choices=['debug', 'info', 'warning', 'error'],
        help="logging level (defaults to 'warning')"
    )
    parser.add_argument('-j', '--jpeg', help='use JPEG compresion', action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument(
        '-q', '--quality', help='JPEG compresion quality (default 85)', type=int, default=85
    )
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version=__version__)
    parser.add_argument("files", metavar='file', nargs='+', help="one or more files to process")
    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=getattr(logging, args.log.upper(), None), format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s'
    )
    logging.debug(f'command line arguments = {sys.argv}')
    logging.debug(f'parsed arguments = {args}')
    # Check for requisites
    try:
        for prog in ('tiffinfo', 'tiff2pdf'):
            sp.run([prog], stdout=sp.DEVNULL, stderr=sp.DEVNULL)
            logging.debug(f'found “{prog}”')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logging.error(f'required program “{prog}” not found')
        sys.exit(1)
    return args


def tiffconv(fname, jpeg=False, quality=85):
    """
    Start a tiff2pdf process for given file.

    Arguments:
        name: Name of the tiff file to convert.
        jpeg: Use JPEG compression.
        quality: JPEG compression quality.

    Returns:
        A 2-tuple (input filename, tiff2pdf return value).
    """
    try:
        args = ['tiffinfo', fname]
        p = sp.run(args, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.DEVNULL)
        txt = p.stdout.decode().split()
        if 'Width:' not in txt:
            raise ValueError('no width in TIF')
        index = txt.index('Width:')
        width = float(txt[index + 1])
        length = float(txt[index + 4])
        try:
            index = txt.index('Resolution:')
            xres = float(txt[index + 1][:-1])
            yres = float(txt[index + 2])
        except ValueError:
            xres, yres = None, None
        outname = re.sub(r'\.tif{1,2}?$', '.pdf', fname, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        program = ['tiff2pdf']
        if xres:
            args = [
                '-w',
                str(width / xres), '-l',
                str(length / xres), '-x',
                str(xres), '-y',
                str(yres), '-o', outname, fname
            ]
        else:
            args = ['-o', outname, '-z', '-p', 'A4', '-F', fname]
            logging.warning(f"no resolution in {fname}. Fitting to A4")
        if jpeg:
            args = program + ['-n', '-j', '-q', str(quality)] + args
        else:
            args = program + args
        logging.info(f'calling "{args}"')
        rv = sp.run(args, stdout=sp.DEVNULL, stderr=sp.DEVNULL)
        logging.info(f'created "{outname}"')
        return (fname, rv.returncode)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'starting conversion of "{fname}" failed: {e}')
        return (fname, 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```